# Why is there an "@" added in my excel formula created with Python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I'm parsing a lot of data in Python, and use pandas to format at write to excel.

I need to add one column in one of the excel sheets that uses XLOOKUP inn excel to find the row in column `B` of sheet `exchange` where the value in column `A` of `exchange` is equal to column `A` of the current sheet, so I want this in excel:

```
=XLOOKUP(AX, exchange!A:A, exchange!B:B, "Not Found", 0)*GX
```

where `X`(as in `AX` and `GX`) is the current row number.

I use this in python to add a column to the existing df:

```py
        df['Columnn Name'] = df.apply(
            lambda x: f'=XLOOKUP(A{x.name + 2}, exchange!A:A, exchange!B:B, "Not Found", 0)*G{x.name + 2}', axis=1
        )
```

However, when opening the excel sheet, I see that the formula is:

```
=@XLOOKUP(A2, exchange!A:A, exchange!B:B, "Not Found", 0)*G2
```

so with an `@` inserted immediately before the `XLOOKUP`, and the calculation doesn't work (it just shows `#NAME?` in the cell. If I manually remove the `@`, it works as it should. But why on earth is it inserting an `@`, and how do I make it stop?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+excel+at+sign+formula+site:stackoverflow.com You may need to write the formula using openpyxl or xlsxwriter directly, and also research their support for Dynamic Array formulas.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I think I was searching too narrowly, and didn't get any hits.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to prefix XLOOKUP (and a few other excel functions) with `_xlfn.`. So the python code should be:

```py
        df['Columnn Name'] = df.apply(
            lambda x: f'=_xlfn.XLOOKUP(A{x.name + 2}, exchange!A:A, exchange!B:B, "Not Found", 0)*G{x.name + 2}', axis=1
        )
```